# Not able to load an image from .jsp using HTML img tag

Tags: java, spring, jsp, path

I created a small web app using Spring and JSPs. I am trying to load an image using relative path, but I am getting following error:

> 404 : Resource not found

This is my project structure in Eclipse:

[image: Screenshot of Eclipse showing the project tree end JSP source]

What is causing the error and what can I do to solve it?

Comment: have you tried `/src/xxx`? as currently it is searching in webcontent for the folder src

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). From that second link: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it." You also must provide your question **as text**, not as images.

Comment: Have you tried using absolute path? like this
<img src="http://mydomain/servlet/imageServlet?imgid=xyz" />

Comment: Also, [Why may I not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7224597)

Comment: Review: cleaned up text formatting and grammar; clarified title

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are looking for the picture inside the `WebContent` map. And you are trying to get a picture from a different map.

Maybe add a `../` before `src`. I think that should do the trick.

Comment: I tried,but still the I am getting same error 404 :Resource not found

Comment: Did you try: '../MyApplication/Java Recources/src/recource/akashPic.png'.
Don't know if that will do it. I just started coding. I am thinken in HTML with this.

Comment: ../MyApplication/Java Recources/src/recource/akashPic.png  not working.

Comment: ../MyApplication/Java Recources/src/recource/akashPic.png' not working

Comment: oh, my bad. try: '../Java Recources/src/recource/akashPic.png' .

Comment: The MyApplication does not have to be in there

Comment: Thanks for reply and tried with '../Java Recources/src/recource/akashPic.png' .Still not getting the image.

Answer (score 0):

As you are working in jsp, try this:

```
<img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/akashPic.png"/>
```

or this if the first won't works

```
<img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resource/akashPic.png"/>
```

For more info: check **[this](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html)**

Comment: I tried,but still problem is same.Getting error 404 :Resource not found

Comment: And in this way `<img src="resource/akashPic.png"/>` ? should be `resources` instead of `resource` I guess.

Comment: Tried with <img src="resource/akashPic.png"/>